# Resizing images in android and iOS

Tags: android, iphone, ios, image, resize

We have an application, running on `iOS and on Android`. There is a function in app, that loads images to server with specific size ( < 2 mb) So before loading images to the server I need to resize it to reduce image size to successfuly load it to the server.

Is there any solution to make photos compatible with the most part of screen sizes (I need to show full size of image on the screen), running on Android and iOs (no iPad)?

thanks

Comment: Have you checked if there is something you can use from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android

Comment: Are you asking how to resize images from the server to fit the screen of your device? Or are you asking how to resize images from the device to whatever size the server requires?

Comment: I am asking of what is the best image height and width to show it full-size on whole Android devices because for example it's not right to show image 720x480 on 1024x768 screen...

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
private Bitmap decodeBitmapFile(File f,int size,int scal){
    try {         
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);         
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=size;           
        int scale=scal;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale*=2;       
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```