# java.lang.outofmemoryerror exception while trying to display images in gridview

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I am trying to display 6 images, which i have kept in res/drawable folder in the gridview.

but i get the following error

```
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:501)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:354)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:616)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:349)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.shiva.bajarangi.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:55)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1341)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:341)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:283)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:417)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1229)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-29 09:44:20.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my adapter class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mcontext;
    Integer Imageid[] = new Integer[] { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image6,
            R.drawable.image2 };



    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
        this.mcontext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Imageid.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View gridView;
        if(convertView == null){
            gridView = new View(mcontext);

            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageview,null);

            ImageView imageView =(ImageView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
        }
            else {
                gridView = (View) convertView;
            }


        return gridView;
    }

}
```

why is this error?..

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: how large are your images?

Comment: @A.S. 135kb,190kb,73.7kb,154kb,268kb and 500kb. are the image sizes of each image

Comment: load scaled down images into GridView as original images are consuming a lot memory

Comment: @GopalRao can you please explain how to load the scaled images??.. thanks:)

Comment: see johntheripp3r answer...

Comment: @Beginner Had you checked this in real device?

Comment: @YogGuru yea i have checked on real device too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is Happening here is that,,, the app is going out of heap size.So you have to decode the image in such a way that it will fall under the heap size.Do this code in your adapter

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View gridView;
        if(convertView == null){
            gridView = new View(mcontext);

            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageview,null);
            ImageView imageView =(ImageView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inDither = false;
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            options.inSampleSize = 3;
            options.inPurgeable = true;

            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    Imageid[position],options);


            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(icon);
        }
            else {
                gridView = (View) convertView;
            }


        return gridView;
    }
```

Comment: great answer i am also having for same issue but now solve thank you @Akhilesh Sk

Comment: i needed to make small changes in your code.. and it worked for me.. thanks:)

Comment: Using "options" to decodeFile realy helps to me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The images you are using are big. 
Have a look at this [article](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) 
**OR** 
Scale your images down. - reduce their size and quality.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the size of your images according to the individual grid sizes.
Check the link.
[How to resize Image in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android)