# OutOfMemoryError when loading images into GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview, out-of-memory, android-imageview

I am creating an app which loads images in a GridView but depending on the number of images I place in my array I get the *java.lang.outofmemory* error and the app crashes.
I have an ImageAdapter where the loading of the images occurs, I was following this tutorial from [Androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/) . My images in total are about 4.53MB with the largest one being 1.1MB. Some images are fairly smaller. Sometimes when I load the images from my code one at a time the app runs,but when I do all images at once it crashes.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654739/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-exception-while-trying-to-display-images-in-gridview) seemed sensible but I could not follow with the way my project is setup. I just have a GridView and get the ImageView programatically in my code but they seem to reference from xml file.
Here is my `getView()` method:

    `@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbsIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        return imageView;
}`

where the mThumbsId is the integer array that is storing my image references from @drawable folder. I need help resizing the images with the way my project is set up and maybe the other answer can help but I cannot follow their structure. 

 My xml file with the gridview as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="150dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth" > 

</GridView>
```

Thanx in advanced

Comment: The size in Megabytes does not matter that much. How big is the size of the images in terms of resolution?

Comment: largest one 1161*1161 and smallest one is 350*350 I just got them off the internet. Should I resize? @PhilippJahoda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of 1161x1161 pixels you mentioned  is internally converted into a `Bitmap`. This Bitmap (if 32Bit) will occupy approximately 5MB (1161 x 1161 x 4 bytes) of heap memory.

Since you will have multiple of these images in memory when used in a `GridView`, it is no surprise you run out of memory. So **yes, you should resize your images** before loading them into the `GridView`.

Read this question/answer on **how to resize**: [High resolution Image - OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385362/high-resolution-image-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: using your solution and setting the imageview using the imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource()) method worked. Thanx @PhilippJahoda