# resize image before upload to server using php and android

Tags: java, android, json, image, resize

Im using the code below to upload an image to the server using java and PHP, i works fine, but i would like to resize the image before upload to the server, can some help me how to do that THANKS!!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private TextView messageText;
    private Button uploadButton, btnselectpic;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    private String upLoadServerUri = null;
    private String imagepath=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        btnselectpic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
        imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);

        btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.0.15/UploadToServer.php";
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(arg0==btnselectpic)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
        }
        else if (arg0==uploadButton) {

             dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
             messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {

                      uploadFile(imagepath);

                 }
               }).start();     
        }

    } 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath(); 

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);

        }
    }
         public String getPath(Uri uri) {
                String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


          String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

               dialog.dismiss(); 

               Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
                   }
               }); 

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                             + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                      +" F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                                messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog.dismiss();       
              return serverResponseCode; 

           } // End else block 
         }


}
```

And php code is

```
< ?php

   $file_path = "uploads/";

   $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
       echo "success";
   } else{
       echo "fail";
   }
? >
```

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android ? You may want to make that a background process ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always try : http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/

Very easy to use.

then you just do :

```
 BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
           image = Scalr.resize(image, 150);
```

in the .resize you pass in the imgFile and then the size you want. I put 150 here just as an example

Comment: Thanks, your solution works fine, but I solve it in PHP, becuase the performance

Comment: But if you dont do it on your Android Device you consume more bandwidth and increase the file transfer.
You mind posting the way you did it in PHP.

Comment: How should I use this library in android studio ?  can anyone give a hint >?