# Android - Resize image before BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns it

Tags: android, android-bitmap, shrink

I need to resize/shrink the image which I am selecting from my gallery before it is returned from `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imagestream)`. It throws `OutOfMemory Exception` when I have selected to large image. How could I resize the image before it is returned from decodeStream?

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICKER_SELECT
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            InputStream imageStream = null;
            try {
                imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            imgV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            // sb = bitmap;
            // imgSelected = true;
            selectedImage = null;
            imageStream = null;
            bitmap = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Refer [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android).

Comment: @Sash_KP : the link you provided deals with bitmap, but the OP is having problem decoding the bitmap, and that's the reason why he wants to resize. `How could I resize the image before it is returned from decodeStream` he wants to resize using `imagestream`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it this way

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize=2; //decrease decoded image 
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options); 
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fos);
```

Comment: what is fos in .compress, is it necessery?

Comment: @user3245899 fos is a fileoutputstream