# Taking a Photo and show it in AlertDialog in original Size

Tags: android, android-imageview

Today i played around with using the device camera. For 
that i implemented the following:

```
private void performAddPhoto() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if(intent.resolveActivity(this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, Globals.REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
    } else {

    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == Globals.REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");

            this.imageViewPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

So i take a photo and i show it in my ImageView. The ImageView is much smaller
than the original size of the photo. However now i added an OnClickListener to
my ImageView to show the Photo in an AlertDialog:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    this.imageViewPhoto.setOnClickListener(this);
    ...
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    ...
    this.performShowPhoto();
    ...
}

private void performShowPhoto() {
    ImageView clone = new ImageView(this);
    clone.setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable)this.imageViewPhoto.getDrawable()).getBitmap());

    DialogManager.showImageDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_photo), clone);
}
```

Now the Photo is shown in the AlertDialog but in exact the same size like it was 
in the ImageView. How can i show the Photo in original Size taken by the camera?
Or at least just a little bit smaller to fit the AlertDialog into the Screen.

Comment: take a look at this question and the appropriate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android

Comment: ehm yes... but that creates a stretched and pixeled presentation... i need the original photo with the original camera resolution.

Comment: I think you need to created a custom AlertDialog by extending the Dialog class in order to achive your desired result

Comment: why should that change anything? I would again have the same bitmap.