# How to set all image at the same size

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview, android-image

anyone knows how can I to make all that images from my [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5H8v.jpg) to have the same size/form, more exactly I want all my images to have the square form.

Here is my [both XML](http://www.filedropper.com/desktop_8), sry but I cant post the code here because it's to big and don't let me

Comment: If my answer is wrong could we get your list xml?

Comment: set a fixed height and width to the imageview

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize Image in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android)

Comment: No, it's not duplicate because I don't want that kind type of resize. I want to make all my images same, I don't want to make more little at size.

Comment: I can't  see your XML

Comment: U need to download it, click on "both XML", I cant post it because it's to big, and don't let me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we can refer to this question : [How to resize Image in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android)

You may make an array of all your images and than itarete thorugh this array and use the method shown below on all of your files.

```
Bitmap yourBitmap;
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

Comment: I don't want that kind of resize because I've already use it. But it don't help me for my problem, but make my images more little.

Comment: It doesn't have to be more little,i guess.You can specify the exact sizes in newWidth and newHeight.Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a list, you're probably using a custom adapter to inflate the list with the elements (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews).
So you could just adjust your "listitem.xml" file, so that every created list element has the same size.

Something like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgID"
        android:src="@drawable/src_img"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt you set it in your xml to have a set height/ width and presumably height to also = width?  If its like this you might be doing wrap content.

Answer (score 0):

In lisitem XML layout set imagview height to fixed dp like 150,200 dp.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/db_two" />
```