# buttons don't show up or remove each other in GridLayout

Tags: java, android, image, android-layout, layout

Here is my problem: **When some of the images get placed in the GridLayout the other app images around them disappear.** I've noticed that the image that seem to "push out" the other images from the view have really big IMAGES

Comment: Can you post your layout and the code that populates the layout? I don't think that the error message about the adapter is indicative of the problem.

Comment: @Cheticamp I updated with the Layout Xml file. Please let me know if you see anything. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Is that XML all in one file or did you append a couple of different layouts together? I don't see the XML for your GridLayout.

Comment: @Cheticamp the XML is just one file and I define my gridlayout in the corresponding java file ^^^ Above. Just edited :)

Comment: Your XML makes no sense. You seem to be mixing the button layout with the container layout - the two should be separate. Can you post the code where you actually create each button and add it to the adaptor.

Comment: @Cheticamp I posted how the button is created in my edits. What is the container view that I should be separating from the button view? How would I separate this while still updating the gridview with the buttons? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @adelphus Please check my update. Thank you very much for looking into this!

Comment: That is making more sense, although I am still not sure about the XML. If you haven't already tried it, take a look at `ImageView.ScaleType` that you can set in your XML or with Java code. It may be what you need to crop your images to your ImageButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will outline some areas in the XML that may be causing you some problems. First, you need an XML layout file that 
looks something like the following that will hold your top-level layout. This will be in its own file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Notice that the RecyclerView stands alone within the LinearLayout. You will next need a separate XML file
that will hold the layout for the ImageButton and TextView for each cell of your layout. This will fit into each 
cell of the grid in your RecyclerView. I used `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` to fit large images into the ImageButton.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/new_app_button"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/new_app_button"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`onCreateViewHolder()` of `RecyclerViewHolder` will look like the following assuming "grid_cell.xml" is the name
of the XML file above.

```
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.grid_cell, parent, false);
    RecyclerViewHolders holder = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
    return holder;
}
```

Give this a try. I think that everything else is OK. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much it solved the problem! I'll approve your question now :) - Emily

Comment: Wasn't there a 50 bounty on this question?

Comment: Yep, 50 points was removed from me and from what I read after I made your answer the correct one by giving you the green mark you should of gotten the 50 transferred to you.... unless it waits for 7 days, not fully sure how it works

Comment: I don't think bounties are awarded automatically to the accepted answer until the end of the bounty period plus the grace period. I ask because ALL mention of the bounty has disappeared from your question which I found to be odd.

Comment: hmm your right, the bounty isn't showing up. I can message the admin. and ask what happened so you can get your bounty. It was withdrawn from me so yea I'd like you to have it :)

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's all settled.