# Android-Make TextView to fill all the remaining space in layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

I have a news activity with `ImageView` and `TextView` with news content. I want to make news content fill all the space.

The news content filled all the space to the right of image view, so the text was placed to the right of picture, but under the picture it was free space. I decided to put the `ImageView` and `TextView` in separated linear layout. But the text disappeared after the area right from image was filled.

The problem is displayed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/853Ha.png).

My questions are:

1. How I can place the remaining text under the image view?
2. How I can make the picture to keep his height/width ratio?

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.tutorialsbuzz.phrasebook.NewsActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewHeaderNews"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewDateNews"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="header"
            android:textColor="@color/mycolor"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/newslayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewHeaderNews"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewNews"
                android:layout_width="165dp"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/world"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewContentNews"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="jklasdf as ;AJFWADLHF LAS HFLAF VANLASN: l galgsalgngan  ;wafasldwlaf alla lnaf alf lg;aeguewaf hwla hfnalgh wa
                j;fklasgj;s;nva;   alsf las ps z; laszfj alsz vzlxg a lrg z;dnlxfdj glzf ;f glaerzlls az
                ;asdjk  aF{ af[ [D{j  as ;as ; wjv a jkn da weq  g ; aeskj; g ;eakr;ja r"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDateNews"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="date"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewViewsNews"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/newslayout"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:text="views"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/newslayout"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:text="rating"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRatingNews"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinnerRatingNews"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinnerRatingNews"
            android:text="Գնահատեք."
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerRatingNews"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewRating"
            android:layout_margin="3dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well its pretty complex to explain (for me anyway).
There is no way to do it with xml but you can do it through code,I will refer your to post I used to achive the same resault as you want. (wrap textview around other view).

[Read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image)

the above like is what I used and its have pretty nice resault.

You requested in the comment to resize your image btu to keep its ratio.

[This is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android) about the subject of resizing image.

first check if the image is larger then X if it is then resize it with factor that match your needs.

Comment: Thank You. And how to make the ImageView to keep his height/width ratio?

Comment: well you hard coded its height/width so you cant keep his original height/width ratio. you can use wrap_content instead.

Comment: But I need different images for different news, with different height and width. So I need to place them in my ImageView keeping their view.

Comment: well I didn't understood from your comment what is the problem with "wrap_content"?

Comment: Because there could be uploaded images with big dimensions (e.g. by content writers).

Comment: Well you need to do this using code then. I will update my answer.