# How to resize a Bitmap image in Android

Tags: java, android, textview, android-bitmap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingLeft="32dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
    <item android:bottom="3dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_publish_black_24dp" />
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#37474f" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This is how I call it:

```
TextView aboutBags = new TextView( mContext );
aboutBags.setText("Compose");
aboutBags.setTextAppearance( R.style.RevStyleHelpAbout );
aboutBags.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.rev_item_h_border_left );
```

I've tried border attributes `android:width="22dp" android:height="22dp"` all over the XML, but the image doesn't get resized.

How can I resize the bitmap image?

Vielen dank im voraus.

Answer (score 7):

Using [**Bitmap**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) may help you. Use like this:

```
Bitmap nameYourBitmap;

Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(nameYourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

You can also do like this:

```
resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(nameYourBitmap,(int)(nameYourBitmap.getWidth()*0.8), (int)(nameYourBitmap.getHeight()*0.8), true);
```

Refer to this: [How to resize Image in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android)

For XML, the scale attributes are defined for ScaleDrawables, and they can scale another drawable. Please refer to this developer site: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Scale

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Animesh Patra. Can I do it inside the XML.

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev You are welcome. If my answer was any help, you may accept it for future reference to others.