# Bitmap.createScaledBitmap is not working to resize the image

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I am trying to implement one code where user will add image and the size of image should be less then 3MB if the size is greater then it will resize automatically. I know this question is repeated asking but my code is not working properly.

Below is my code

```
  Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            bitmap2 = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            Log.e("path of image 4", picturePath + "");
            String str = String.valueOf(bitmap2.getRowBytes() * bitmap2.getHeight());
            Log.e("lengh of bitmap.......", str);
          //  Log.e("lengh of bitmap", String.valueOf(bitmap2.getAllocationByteCount()));

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

            Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, 200, 300, true);

            imageView2.setImageBitmap(resized);
            setImage("image2");
```

[I have tried this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android)

[And this](https://android.jlelse.eu/loading-large-bitmaps-efficiently-in-android-66826cd4ad53)

Comment: duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize Image in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android)

Comment: @T I know this is duplicate question that's why I wrote on question " this question is repeated" please check question

Comment: @TentenPonce and ADM please check question. And I have already tried this which link you both send me. I hope you will read my question again thanku.

Comment: @user6734679 "my code is not working properly" is not sufficient as a problem description. You need to tell us *exactly* what's happening that you don't expect *and* what you are expecting to happen, along with providing a [MCVE] which duplicates the problem (including any needed input data). People have pointed out a duplicate, and you have mentioned it in the question. It is incumbent upon *you* to [edit] the question to demonstrate that it's not a duplicate (e.g. show *exactly* what you tried and explain what happened (i.e. *exactly* what is "not working properly")).

Comment: Okay thanku @Makyen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HI as per my understanding, You can  do this and also you can follow [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android)

```
Bitmap yourBitmap;
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

or:

```
resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap,(int)(yourBitmap.getWidth()*0.8), (int)(yourBitmap.getHeight()*0.8), true);
```

**Also You can use this method**

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {

int width = bm.getWidth();
int height = bm.getHeight();
float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
// create a matrix for the manipulation
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
// resize the bit map
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
// recreate the new Bitmap
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

return resizedBitmap;

 }
```

Comment: I have tried this but not working please check my code again

Comment: I have updated my answer.You can use method as I my answer

Comment: Can you tell me exact that when I am using above code it's not working

Comment: It still gives same size after and before save the image.

Comment: *Please*, indent your code and use one [indenting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) consistently throughout your code. Doing so makes it **much** easier to read/maintain. Doing so for code you place on Stack Overflow makes it much more likely both that users will up-vote your posts and that people will put time into Answering your Questions. It doesn't really matter which style your choose (although, for some languages, some styles are more appropriate than others). But, *pick one* and *use it consistently* for all code in a single project.