# High quality(image taken by phone camera) make feed laggy (slow) in android, solution?

Tags: java, firebase

The high-quality image also takes to download(from firebase) and display, also make feed slow and laggy once we scroll and the image is out of screen then feed gets back to normal
https://pastebin.com/ibcaGzVH This has code on how I upload the image and selection of it

This is how I fetch display the image in feed:

```
 public void setPimage(Context ctx, String pimage) {
            ImageView popic = mView.findViewById(R.id.imgView_postpic);
            if (pimage != "noImage") {
                popic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Picasso.with(ctx).load(pimage).into(popic);
            }
        }
```

Any way to remove that slowness due to image and make retrieving of image faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the size of the image is causing slowness in uploading, downloading and processing it, you may want to resize the image to be smaller before uploading it.

There are many ways to [resize an image in an Android app](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+resize+image), but here's a top result from that list: [How to resize Image in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android)